# Bleeding Brakes 2002 Bonneville with ABS

Tags: brakes, pontiac, bonneville, bleeding

I had to replace the 2 brake lines that go from the master cylinder to the ABS control box. I bled all 4 brakes in the proper order, (RR,LR,RF,LF) but the brakes are minimal and the pedal goes to the floor. The master cylinder is full.

Also, I could not get the rear bleeder bolts loose and did not want to twist them off, thus I bled the rear brakes at the brake hose going into the caliper....Is this acceptable?

***What am I missing?***

***Should I have attempted to bleed these lines at the control box?***

Thanks.

Comment: If the master cylinder ever ran dry, it might need to be "bench bled" to properly remove air.  Also, ABS units typically have their own, often electronic method for bleeding.  I don't know what the procedure for your car is, but I'm sure it needs to be done.

Comment: You might want to try bench bleeding the ABS unit.  You can have bubbles stuck in there that you will almost never be able to get out through standard bleeding methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bleeding Brakes](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/28279/bleeding-brakes)

Comment: I think the question is unique and does not overlap with the other question.

Comment: I'd say the *other question is the duplicate here*. Not this one.

Answer (score 4):

**Your procedure for bleeding is fine, except for the banjo bolt**

You can bleed a line at the banjo bolt but you can't bleed a caliper.

You can get your stuck nipple off if you break the head by using a bolt extractor.  If you use a bolt extractor and have to drill it out in any way you will NEED to disassemble the caliper to ensure it does not have any metal shavings in it.

**Tools**

Two effective brake bleeding tools are speedbleeders or vacuum evacuation tools.

***Here is a speedybleeder**

[image]

Here is handheld vacuum pump.

[image]

Comment: I have never seen a speedybleeder on a car and I have opened thousands of bleeders.  Are they new on the market?

Comment: @FredWilson  They were popularized by the Brits and they've begun to come over here.  I have two on an old Suzuki.  I just did it's first high speed run two weeks ago and they were fine.  Just buble balanced them in with some rim weights and off we went.  nothing super crazy, just 120mph on an abandoned desert road.  They seem fine.  Check back in a month and I'l tell you if they're worth a crap.

Comment: I'm betting they will fine.  So simple.  Like them thus far.  A lot.