# Bleeding Brakes

Tags: brakes, pontiac, bonneville

Also with regard to my 2002 Bonneville brake bleeding question, I could  not get the rear bleeder bolts loose and did not want to twist them off, thus I bled the rear brakes at the brake hose going into the caliper....Is this acceptable? Thanks

Comment: This will get the air out of the lines, but it will introduce a _small_ amount of air back into the line when you make the hose connection.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can still have air trapped in the rear caliper/wheel cylinder.  Removing the line could introduce air to the caliper or wheel cylinder.

Unfortunately, this means you might end up replacing your rear calipers / wheel cylinders also.  It has happened to me a number of times.  Be sure to spray it with some good penetrating oil and use a 6 point socket.